# What are the ways to make radioactive water drinkable again?

Tags: radioactivity, water-treatment

Let's say survivors in the area contaminated by radioactive fallout need to somehow process the water from rivers, rain or pipes. How could they go about it? Is it even possible to 'remove radioactivity' from the water?

Answer (score -2):

The water itself isn't radioactive, rather particles dissolved in it, because water is a quite good solvent. Therefore, filtration (e.g. with activated carbon) or precipitation can remove such particles. Also a ion exchanger can remove radioactive species. But this can take quite long, especially if the needed amount is large.

Comment: Thermonuclear explosions produce a large amount of tritium. Can't filter that out, because it's likely bound in *water*.

Comment: I'll point out that all surface water has tritium, even before mankind split the atom.

Comment: @Karl OP was not specific about the nature of the radioactive contamination, but the amount of tritium produced by nuclear weapons are generally not a serious threat due to there extreme dilution and short lifetime in body. You also can effectively cure it by drinking normal water.

Comment: @Karl - what mechanism produces ‘large’ amounts of tritium? Particularly compared with all the fission byproducts?

Comment: @Jon Custer: Compared to the total natural amount of $\pu{3.5 kg}$ tritium in the atmosphere, the amount produced by nuclear explosions or in nuclear rectors is large (CANDU reactors e.g. produce $\pu{1 kg}$ tritium per $\pu{5 GWa}$).

Comment: @aventurin - a stated mechanism would allow rough quantification. An unboosted primary will make essentially no tritium.

Comment: The following link shows tritium measured in Ottawa (Canada). It has a large spike in 1964 due to nuclear testing (note that the scale is logarithmic) http://snobear.colorado.edu/Daniel/isotopes/tritium.html

Comment: @JonCuster A thermonuclear bomb breeds tritium out of lithium (Li+n->T+He), which then gets fused with deuterium (D+T->He+n). Naturally some of the T escapes the fusion.

Comment: @Karl - I don't dispute the 'some' - I dispute that it is a 'large amount'. Beyond the tritium either from boost or the secondary, that is about it. The cross section for D(n,g)T is quite small (heck, the 3He(n,p)T reaction has a higher cross section).

Comment: @JonCuster The main "explosive" is lithiumdeuteride, and Li gets split into T + He-4 (plus one additional neutron from Li-7). D + Li + n -> D + T + He -> 2 He + n. There is necessarily one equivalent of tritium in the reaction, isn't there? Natural water does not get activated strongly, of course.

Comment: @Karl - the main explosive in the secondary is the U or Pu - the D-T reaction is there to kick-start it with a pulse of neutrons. The energy from D-T fusion is a small percentage of the total output.

Comment: @JonCuster Either you or I have some wrong idea (or different nomenclature) about thermonuclear bombs. My understanding is primary=Pu fission, secondary=LiD (10-30 times as "large"), optional tertiary=U-238. But OK, de:wp also says that tritium is used up almost completely. Not sure how, do they put in some extra deuterium?